# Set watermark in video xamarin.forms android

Tags: android, xamarin, ffmpeg

i'm working upon app which can add watermark to video file,
i'm using FFMPEG in xamarin.forms of android version to add watermark in video,
my question is when i'm trying to add border with this command

```
drawbox=y=ih/PHI:color=black@0.4:width=iw:height=48:t=max,
```

why is this `t=max` returning errors?

```
[Parsed_drawbox_1 @ 0xb7fd3ce0] [Eval @ 0xbeb2e520] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'max'

[Parsed_drawbox_1 @ 0xb7fd3ce0] Error when evaluating the expression 'max'
```

Comment: Can you please post more information, where does the value `max` come from?

Comment: It comes from the docs, which appear to have an example with an incomplete string. It should be `max(a,b)` where a and b are numerals or one of the accepted constants listed at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox